Почему не получается отправить post запрос на jut.su?
Мне нужно парсить найденные аниме, с помощью отправки post запроса по адресу: jut.su/search/"анимешка". Но моя проблема появилась еще в начале, при тестировании запросов на сам сайт, я стал получать исключение: "System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение..
". Также на сайт не заходит и через браузер без впн. Вот код моего метода:
public async Task<Anime> Search(JutsuFilter filter)
{
    Anime anime = new Anime("none");
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    handler.UseCookies = true;
    handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://jut.su");
    }
    return anime;
}

Ещё я хотел бы узнать, есть ли способ решить эту проблему без использования прокси, или если это единственный вариант, то есть ли возможность не арендовывать их, а использовать какой-нибудь бесплатный?

Да вроде на днях какие-то анимешные сайты опять Роскомнадзор забанил

@CrazyElf Походу обойтись без прокси мне не удастся(

Скачайте тор бандл (не браузер), запустите его фоном самой программой и через него пускайте трафик. ИМХО, самый надежный способ для разработчиков. А так да,, сайт заблокирован в РФ.
